# Call API every 30 seconds in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to call api every 30 seconds.
I already tried to do it with setInterval but it did not really work out.

Any suggestions?

```
 componentDidMount() {
        const {getCurrencies, setPageCount,loadData} = this.props.actions
         agent
            .get('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=XXX')
            .then(res => {
                getCurrencies(res.body.data)
                setPageCount()
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not really work out." `setInterval` should work for this use-case.

Comment: I was doing it but in the middle one of my friends said that's it dangerous to use setInterval because it would "eat my data storage"

Comment: `setInterval` is the way to go here - ask your friend to elaborate what "eating your data storage" means.